# How to do SQL query to get a list of value at a certain date, from a table with start date and end date

Tags: sql, date-range

I have two tables:

**Material** {IDMat, Label, Model} and
**ReservationMat** (IDRes, IDMat, StartDate, EndDate)

How can I get list of all materials that is available (not reserved) on certain date ?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: hello, both tables are relations in SQL. Do I answer your question ?

Comment: By SQL you mean Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: I haven't used Mic SQL Server, at the moment I am just using interface web phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your are using MySql as database engine.
You could use a query like this:

```
select * from material where idmat in (
  select idmat from reservationmat
  where '2022-01-07' not between startdate and enddate
);
```

Please refer to this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c68c50/1/4) for the complete schema and data used to test